# Has a court ever struck down an election result in the United States?

Tags: united-states, election, separation-of-powers

A number of observers have raised the issue of court challenges to the 2016 US presidential election results.

Various rationales might be employed. For instance,

1. Harvard Law prof. Larry Lessig has discussed the possible unconstitutionality of winner-take-all allocation of electors under the Equal Protection Clause [here](https://medium.com/@lessig/the-equal-protection-argument-against-winner-take-all-in-the-electoral-college-b09e8a49d777#.b5z5sio9h).
2. Former CIA officer Robert Baer has stated [here](http://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2016/12/10/robert-baer-new-election-russia-hacking-nr.cnn) that if ample evidence is presented that Russia intervened in the election through information warfare, a rerun of the election might be justified.
3. There is ample polling evidence that the Clinton campaign was damaged by FBI Director James Comey reopening the Clinton email investigation shortly before the election. The election may have hinged on this intervention. Comey's actions may have constituted a violation of the Hatch Act, which prohibits him from interfering in elections.

Have any American elections (at any level) ever been overturned by the courts before? In the case of rationales (2) and (3), what possible legal doctrines could be employed?

Comment: This feels like at least 3 excellent questions. 1. Have any elections been overturned before? 2. What legal rationale could be used to justify Baer's claim? and 3. What legal rationale could be used to justify Director Comey's claim?

Comment: The FBI investigates crimes, a complete stretch if not an out right slander to compare that to political grandstanding. If anything she got off easy

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/1994/02/19/us/vote-fraud-ruling-shifts-pennsylvania-senate.html

Comment: @KDog The FBI has internal regulations about publicizing politically sensitive investigations close to elections, which Comey knowingly violated. Hence it is a possible Hatch Act violation (using his office to interfere in the electoral process).

Comment: @ColinZwanziger Having read the letter that Comey sent, it was addressed to about a dozen senators who were either party leaders or involved in investigations into the email server.  Comey didn't send the letter to the press, he sent it out to some senators.  It would be the senators or their staff who must have leaked it to the public.

Comment: Colin, cite the regulations.  A policy and regulations are different things.

Comment: @acpilot 1. FBI regulations prohibit commenting on politically sensitive matters within 60 days of an election http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/31/politics/eric-holder-op-ed-rips-comey-letter/ 2. The Hatch Act prohibits "use [ing] official authority or influence for the purpose of interfering with or affecting the result of an election." .

Comment: @user96037 Such a letter would be immediately leaked, as AG Lynch warned Comey, and as indeed occurred.

Comment: @KDog - making a big announcement of a non-issue about another person that had no relevance, and linking it to a closed investigation just before the election date is unprecedented behavior and absolutely justifies a comparison to political grandstanding, as evidenced by the fact that what was found was exactly as I described it.  Indeed, even his report to the Senate where he talked about all the things he didn't like, while also saying none of them came close to criminal behavior, was unprecedented, as well.

Comment: @colin, the opinion piece notes that he broke protocol, not regulation. Regulations are laws, protocol is not. Big difference. I'd love to see the evidence that Comey used "official authority to influence for the purpose of interfering with or affecting the result of an election." Did the investigation effect the election...almost certainly. Was that Comey's intent...maybe, maybe not. Perhaps anger should be directed at Hillary's failure to adhere to regulations (not protocol) regarding InfoSec and not at Comey for doing his job (investigating crimes). Just a thought.

Comment: @acpilot well let's not have a debate over the meaning of the word "regulation". As to whether he used "official authority to influence for the purpose of interfering with or affecting the result of an election", I am not sure what legal standards there are for showing that and thus how good of a case there would be against him. Nevertheless, his intervention was inappropriate and indeed broke protocol

Comment: It's an important word with an important meaning. "Beyond a reasonable doubt" is the legal standard you're looking for.  Comey's "intervention" is what happens when the FBI investigates criminals.

Comment: @acpilot google defines regulation as "a rule or directive made and maintained by an authority." I was using it in the sense of directive.

Comment: As to legal doctrines, my point was that I don't know what the case law is and whether the Hatch Act was successfully enforced in similar situations. Clearly if you, who are the sum total of your experiences and biases ,etc, were on a jury, you would find there is a reasonable doubt. Others with different experiences and biases might find differently.

Comment: It's not about "experiences!" It's rule of law.  Rather than just googling a term, perhaps a better question is "what is the difference between regulation and policy?" It so happens an answer exists: http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-policy-and-vs-regulation/.

Answer (score 11):

### Courts have over-turned elections

While researching another question, I found the case of [McNally v Tollendar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=10000617351228478874&q=2001%20WI%20App%2020&hl=en&as_sdt=4,50&as_vis=1) in which the Michigan state court over-turned a recall election for county office. There were procedural irregularities which caused about 40% of eligible voters to be unable to vote.

This case was notable because it established a new (and relevant) exception. Typically, a court can only overturn an election when it's clear that some irregularities *caused* the election to be decided unfairly.  With this case, the court of Michigan decided that in cases of extreme irregularity the courts can overturn an election without regard to the actual effect of the irregularity.

Comment: This only addresses one of the questions in the question. I kept my response narrow in anticipation of the question being edited down.

Answer (score 9):

## Yes, on multiple occasions.

This generally happens when ruling on the validity of votes during recounts. A good recent example of this is the [2016 Alaska Democratic Primary between Benjamin Nageak and Dean Westlake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Nageak). Westlake originally won by 21 votes, then the recount brought it down to only 4 votes. After a challenge in the Alaskan Supreme court Nageak ended up the victor by 2 votes.

For your second question, I don't know of any case where the courts ruled themselves unable to overturn election results due to separation of powers, but I don't think its very realistic to have such a case. Elections are governed by laws, and it is the responsibility of the judicial branch to resolve disputes over laws. Those laws could also be considered the doctrines to answer your third question.

Comment: Apparently it was actually an appellate court which reversed the primary result, and the Alaska supreme court reinstated the original result.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger Ah right, misread that one a bit. The point remains though - the courts can and on occasion do overturn election results

Answer (score 3):

Here's another one:

http://www.nytimes.com/1994/02/19/us/vote-fraud-ruling-shifts-pennsylvania-senate.html

1994, Pennsylvannia State Senate:

> a Federal judge today took the rare step of invalidating the vote and ordered the seat filled by the Republican candidate.

Answer (score -4):

[Bush v. Gore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_v._Gore) might be relevant here! What short memories we have.

> the actual statewide Florida recount with disputed ballots containing overvotes (where a voter hole-punches multiple candidates but writes out the name of their intended candidate) would have resulted in Gore emerging as the victor by between 60 and 171 votes,

Comment: But this involved upholding the election result, not overturning it.  Note that none of the scheduled recounts used that exact method of counting the votes that would have resulted in a Gore win.  And yes, that includes the recount that was stopped by Bush v. Gore.  From your source:  "Likewise, if Florida's 67 counties had carried out the hand recount of disputed ballots ordered by the Florida Supreme Court on December 8, applying the standards that election officials said they would have used, Bush would have emerged the victor by 493 votes."